# Dungeon Quest: a twisting and turning imgur-maze maze

Tags: visual, mazes, imgur-maze

You've come to this strange dungeon in search of lost treasure. You've reached the final floor and the door has sealed behind you. All you have are your wits, a clue picked up on the previous floor and the following poem:

> *Arrows point the way,*
>   *Circles return the next day.*
>   *Squares twist, curl and spin,*
>   *Red opens doors so you win.*

Goal:
Find and unlock a hidden treasure chest. You will need four keys to do it.

**Map:**
[image]
You start on the red square.

**Starting Clue:**
[image]

**Notes:**
Every image that is part of the puzzle has the same blue DQ circle icon in the corner.
Some partial URL's are not used; there are fake images behind them if you start guessing.

---

Hint:

> Full squares mark a change in instruction type. Square angles point you onward based on where you were.

Hint:

> The second key hides one door south of the first.

Answer (score 3):

## Partial Answer

My interpretations of the clues:

> - Star, square: Directions coming up are of type (arrow/corner). Face north.
>  - Arrow: Go in the direction of the arrow.
>  - Corner: Turn right if the corner is ┌ , and left if the corner is ┐. Afterwards, take a step forward. (Stay facing your new direction.)
>  - Circle: Copy the direction from the previous circle into this spot.

Following the directions given in the starting clue

> leads you to pick up the M with the red arrow and end in `azFN_`. This brings you to:
>  [image]
>  The squares must be related to turning somehow, but I'm not sure how to interpret them. "Circles return the next day" implies to me that a circled instruction "`...A(B)CD...`" is shorthand for `...ABCBD...`, but I'm not certain about this.

If we interpret

> squares as "turn in this direction, then move one step forward", we get to:
>   [image]

Now,

> we can interpret the circle as "do whatever was previously in the circle". Last time, it was a leftwards arrow, so we must need to go left at the circle.

Following those instructions leads us to...

> the chest? But we only have one key...
>  [image]

Comment: My confusion increases. I followed those instructions twice just now. Once I got what you got and once I got the correct next door. If you pick up an "8", you've got it right.

Comment: Wait. "square: Directions coming up are of type (arrow/corner). Face north" is wrong. Do not change facing.

Answer (score 2):

See Deusovi's answer for the first clue.

This is (probably) step 2.

> Following from where we ended up,
>
>  <s>the squares seem to be sort of strange, but seem like multiple instructions in a row. Basically, moving in an L shape. (This might be incorrect, but it led to an image, so it could work.)</s> OP has said that this isn't correct, but this image is the correct next step.
>
>  If we take the I at the red spot, we end up at AiZF_, and we get this image.
>
>  [image]

Comment: What did the circle do? Was I right about that? (Also, how did the full square work?)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are, because it ended up on an image.

Comment: How did the full square work, and how did you decide which direction to go for the corners?

Comment: Er, the square, I just went in a circle, and ended up at the same spot. And I went clockwise for the corners, since counterclockwise with the square sent me through a wall.

Comment: Then I have absolutely no idea what happened.

Comment: You might have followed them perfectly for all I know. You describing your path as an L shape is throwing me off. Without spoiling too much, I can say that each symbol moves you one space or less.